# pam_radius_auth : DEBUG : getservbyname(radius,udp) returned -1217119556 on DEBIAN 9.6

Tags: debian, pam, freeradius, debian-stretch

I have two debian servers connected.
I set FreeRADIUS on a Debian Server (10.10.10.20). And I'd like the another Debian Server (10.10.10.10) can login locally using the users listed on RADIUS Server. I use libpam-radius-auth. But when I try to login locally using the RADIUS user, It keeps fail and the log says "pam_radius_auth : DEBUG : getservbyname(radius,udp) returned -1217119556".

Anyone can tell me how to fix this problem?

OS : Debian 9.6

Here are my configs :

1. RADIUS SERVER

   > /etc/freeradius/3.0/users
   >    (at the last line I add :  **users2 Cleartext-Password := "user"**)
   >   /etc/freeradius/3.0/clients.conf
   >    (at the last line)
   >     **client 10.10.10.10 {
   >             ipaddr = 10.10.10.10
   >             nastype = other
   >             secret = admin123
   >     }**

   2. Another Debian Server that use libpam-radius-auth

      > /etc/pam_radius_auth.conf
      >   i add :

      **server[:port]             SharedSecret             Timeout(s)**

      **10.10.10.20                     admin123                         7**

   > /etc/pam.d/common-auth
   >    i add on the last line :

   **auth sufficient pam_radius_auth.so**

   > I also create homedirectory and login shell for user2 with command:

   **adduser --disabled-password user2**

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, but mine was resolved when I added the home directory and login shell with `adduser --disabled-password :v`